# This is the question about "Very" elementary vector for high school student.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Find a nonzero vector $u=(x,y,z)$ with initial point $A=(-1, 4,-4)$ such that $u$ is the same length but oppositely directed to $v = (7,5,-9)$. Find the terminal point, $B=(a,b,c)$, of $u$.

I got the answer for $u = (-7, -5, 9)$, but I have no idea about point $B$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You solved for the direction vector $-v$ that has the same length and opposite direction to $v$.  The question asks you to find the vector with direction vector $-v$ that starts at point $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Just add $u$ to $\overrightarrow{OA}$, the vector pointing from the origin to $A$ sharing coordinates with $A$. Then you get $\overrightarrow{OB}$ as result thus revealing the coordinates of $B$.